# TabWidget in older android versions

Tags: android, tabwidget

I'm developing an app that has a TabHost and it looks OK in android 4.x but it doesn't in older versions.

How could I fix it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use FragmentTabHost with support library.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html

Comment: What you mean with " with support library"? Should I import something like "android.support.v2.app.FragmentTabHost" ?

Comment: Package Explorer > Right click on your project > Android Tools > Add Suport Library.

Comment: Sorry but I can't find it, could you post a screenshot?
I'm using android studio.

Comment: OK. Please copy the file (your-sdk-dir/extras/android/compatibility/vX/android-support-vX) to your project lib dir.